# how to get specific data from two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

i have following tables
comments table:

```
id  user_id question_id comment 
1     2        3          hii
```

users table:

```
id    u_name   user_image 
2     naveen     a.jpg
```

when question_id=3 is selected how to print values like this:

```
user_image     u_name    comment
a.jpg          naveen      hii <br>
```

sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.user_image, u.name, c.comment
FROM users u INNER JOIN comment c
    ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE c.question_id = 2"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<td class="small">'.$rows['name'].'</td>';
echo '<td class="small">'.$rows['user_image'].'</td>';
echo '<td class="small">'.$rows['comment'].'</td>';

}
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.user_image, u.u_name, c.comment
FROM users u INNER JOIN comments c
    ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE c.question_id = 3
```

## SQLFiddle

Comment: i got error:<br>'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'u' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\n\exam\exam\DOCS\bindComment.php on line 16'

Comment: @user5789755 There must be an error in your PHP code, the query should work fine on MySQL.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\n\exam\exam\DOCS\bindComment.php on line 22
0 results

Comment: @user5789755 You should, at the very least, add your PHP code to your original question.  Better yet, open a new question now that your basic query is working.

Comment: This question seems answered. Let's stick a fork in it, upvote, accept, and move on.

Comment: @Drew Emphasis on the fork.  Must make sure it is well-done with a long meandering string of comments.